# Read from a file line by line

Tags: c++, fstream

How can I read from a text file  line by line , then use the same array to save them ..

Comment: you say you have 10 lines - but you are using an array with 8 possible entries?

Comment: i was thinking to save each line into different arrays @progsource

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: this code kept putting everything into the same array that makes it impossible to compute the number at the end of each line , so i was thinking to put each line into an array . @Eric

Comment: Please use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: i am not good with vector even though people say it is easy @Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it seems that you are using `using namespace std;` in your code. [This is highly discouraged.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/3232207) Here is how I would use `std::vector`. First, you have to import the `<vector>` header file.

```
std::ifstream in_file("file.txt");
if (!in_file) { ... } // handle the error of file not existing

std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::string str;

// insert each line into vec
while (std::getline(in_file, str)) {
    vec.push_back(str);
}
```

`std::ifstream`'s `.close()` method is handled in its destructor, so we don't need to include it. This is cleaner, reads more like English, and there are no magical constants. Plus, it uses `std::vector`, which is very efficient.

**Edit:** modification with a `std::string[]` as each element:

```
std::ifstream in_file("file.txt");
if (!in_file) { ... } // handle the error of file not existing

std::vector<std::string[]> vec;
std::string str;

// insert each line into vec
while (std::getline(in_file, str)) {
    std::string array[1];
    array[0] = str;
    vec.push_back(array);
}
```

Comment: I kinda understand what you are saying but i never used , Do you have any ideas if i should save each line into a different array .

Comment: Why would you want each `std::string` line to be in a different array?

Comment: because i want to use those data into different class of object for example  the first line should be a record for a student

Comment: You can then use the `[]` operator or `.at(int)` provided by `std::vector` to access individual elements. For example, if the first `std::string` of the vector is a student's name, then you would have `std::string student_name = vec[0];`.

Comment: I am really bad with vector , do you know any way for array please where i could save every line into an different array , i know will have to convert the last part of the array to integer to computer those number

Comment: Then just use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` and have each inner vector contain one element (each line).

Comment: please help me with the array not vector :(

Comment: What reason would one need to use an array instead of a vector?

Comment: I don't know how to use vector , but i am much better with array ,my question how to save each line into an array

Comment: See the edit above. It can be modified to your use case, but I would strongly encourage learning `std::vector`.

Comment: no vector please :(, I know i will have 10 arrays ,where in my loop should i said that when we are the last item in the line to go to the next line then save it into a new array

Comment: I re-read your original post. By "line" do you mean separate lines or separate words on one single line?

Comment: basically in the first line each item should be save into in array[10] then once we reach the end of the line go to the next one then save each item into a secondarray[10] , the same process should be repeated until we read those 10 lines

Comment: So basically you need an array of arrays. For splitting each individual line up, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/3232207. Otherwise, it will be up to you to figure out how to have 10 (or for that matter, any number) different arrays.

Comment: its all vector , i am screwed :(

Comment: Go through this tutorial: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

Comment: so basically you mean that if i used vector ,i will be able to save every line and access each item of each line

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. Also, normal arrays have a fixed size - what if your input file has a variable number of lines?

Answer (score 0):

Reference to getline says that data is appended to the string

```
Each extracted character is appended to the string as if its member push_back was called.
```

Try resetting the string after the read

Edit

Each time you call getline, line keeps the old content and adds the new data at the end.

```
line = "";
```

Will reset data between each read

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: now do you think if i save each line in a different array would better ? because i want to use those array into my class of object